# OpenCPU using a different version of R as opposed to the R already installed in the system?

Tags: r, rstudio, opencpu

I have R version 3.3.1 running on Ubuntu 16.04. I also have RStudio server running on the same.

Now I install opencpu by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpu/opencpu-1.6 –y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opencpu
```

The apache2 and opencpu services are running fine. I can access RStudio server and OpenCPU home page through

```
http://192.168.1.10/ocpu/
http://192.168.1.10/rstudio/
```

I login to RStudio and check for R version and it says 3.3.1 which is fine.
Now I go to `http://192.168.1.10/ocpu/library/base` and it shows me R version is 3.2.3 which is weird. I need OpenCPU to use R 3.3.1

Comment: Might be your browser caching the page. Try CTRL+R to force a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't have OpenCPU installed but ...

1) Check the `$PATH` you are using from within R via `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.

2) Unless this is overridden the R version used will be the first one found.

3) That is how RStudio finds its version.  OpenCPU may install its own.  Check its documentation. It is possible it brings its own to better control its dependencies across installations.  It also likely that it has something newer than R 3.2.*.

4) You can install R 3.3.2, and by next week R 3.3.3, by following this [README on CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, the PATH already mentions that the R is in /usr/local/bin and it is 3.3.1. RStudio uses this same version. OpenCPU shows it as 3.2.3. Weird!